# How does Runge kutta (RK4) expression expansion?

Tags: numerical-integration, runge-kutta

I don't know the expansion of K3 and K4 in RK4.

The below is taylor of RK4
[image].

where free fall equation given by:

[image].

Definition RK4 of free fall equation:

[image]

where k1 is

[image]

and k2 is

[image]

[image]

and k3 is

[image]

and k4...

I don't know the expansion formula of K3 and K4.
Please tell me about how to expand.

Comment: Please formulate more precisely what you want to achieve. Do you want to theoretically proof or verify the order of the method or do you want to apply the method to some specific ODE system? In the latter case, you are somewhat going in the completely wrong direction. // Also, it has to be $y(x+h)$, or $x(t+h),v(t+h)$, as in general $h\ne 1$. // Your question might be more suitable on math.SE or scicomp.SE, where you also have mathjax for formulas.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52986419/3088138)?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I'd like to expand the formula k3/j3 and k4/j4 and theoretically proof.

Comment: This is off-topic here. Move it to math.SE or scicomp.SE, where you also have mathjax for formulas. Also, to prevent to have to handle too many terms, you do this best for an autonomous system `x'=f(x)` using some tensor notation or Butcher trees.

Comment: See also https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/RK-methods.pdf for an overview of the systematic way to derive the order conditions of Runge-Kutta methods.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I understand. The ref. that you wrote is very good.